# IAR directive for Simulator

Tags: for-loop, simulator, mode, directive, iar

I'm using IAR EWARM 5.4 , I wondered if there is a directive to show the compiler in Simulator mode.
For example, I want a part of my code to be only compiled in Simulator mode but will be ignored in target mode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The compiler don't know if the end result will be executed on the simulator or on the target hardware.

However, you can always defined your own preprocessor symbol, say `MY_SIMULATOR`, when using the simulator. Your code could then check if it present using `#ifdef MY_SIMULATOR`.

*Update*: If you would like to check the difference between the Debug and Release modes, you can check the symbol `NDEBUG`. It is defined in Release mode.

Comment: I could do the way as you mentioned but what I'm wondering is that if there is a predefined directive to show debug mode. The answer seems to be NO. I have searched all user instruction and no luck to find anything useful. Anyway thanks for your comments.